# Regex to match 10 digit exactly with specific pattern

Tags: regex, regex-greedy, regex-group

Say i give a pattern 123* or 1234* , i would like to match any 10 digit number that starts with that pattern. It should have exactly 10 digits.

Example:

Pattern : 123 should match 1234567890 but not 12345678

I tried this regex : (^(123)(\d{0,10}))(?(1)\d{10}).. obviously it didn't work. I tried to group the pattern and remaining digits as two different groups. It matches 10 digits after the captured group (https://regex101.com/). How do i check the captured group is exactly 10 digits? Or is there any good knacks here. Please guide me.

Comment: It is diffiuclt to help if you do not explain the real life scenario, and provide the code you have trouble with. Maybe you need [`(?<!\d)123\d{7}(?!\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/rDv6Zy/2)

Comment: I was trying to block phone numbers that start with certain pattern. The users set any blocking pattern like 123* or 43* etc.. so i need to block all inbound and outbound that matches that pattern. But before hanging up i need to know why the call failed is it because they dialed wrong number of digits or blocked pattern to set the message properly. This regex \b(?=123)\d{10}\b by @randomir seems to have solved that. Thanks for your thoughts in helping solving that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a case for the [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?=123)\d{10}
```

This will match any sequence of exactly 10 digits but only if prefixed with `123`. Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/9X5YMl/1).

Similarly for prefix `1234`:

```
(?=1234)\d{10}
```

Of course, if you know the prefix length upfront, you can use `123\d{7}`, but then you'll have to change range limits with each prefix change (for example: `1234\d{6}`).

---

Additionally, to ensure only isolated groups of 10 digits are captured, you might want to anchor the above expression with a (zero-length) word boundary `\b`:

```
\b(?=123)\d{10}\b
```

or, if your sequence can appear *inside of the word*, you might want to use negative lookbehind and lookahead on `\d` (as suggested in comments by @Wiktor):

```
(?<!\d)(?=123)\d{10}(?!\d)
```

Comment: `(?=123)\d{10}` = `123\d{7}`

Comment: Of course, but as I understand the OP want to vary prefixes, in which case it's easier to use lookahead since the rest of regex doesn't change. I've added a clarification.

Comment: Yes, but it does not really guarantee that you will only match a 10-digit number, you may match `1234567890` in `12345678901234567`.

Comment: The question is unclear on that point, but you're right. I've covered that case in my answer now also.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it simple:

```
import re

text = "1234567890"

match = re.search("^123\d{7}$|^1111\d{6}$", text)
if match:
    print ("matched")
```

Just throw your 2 patterns in as such and it should be good to go!  Note that 123* would catch 1234* so I'm using 1111\d{6} as an example